# How to open a new chrome window with javascript window settings through the command line on a mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, command-line

How can I open a new chrome window from the terminal with properties similar to calling the Javascript function `window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');`

The reason is because I want to create a dock icon with Automator that launches a new chrome window on a specific url without tabs, toolbars, etc.

UPDATE:

It turns out the answer is running chrome in **application mode**. In Windows, you can go to `Tools > Create application shortcuts`, but it's not possible on a mac.

Run the following in the terminal.    `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --app=http://example.com`

There is also a lifehacker article that does this exact same thing and simplifies the process of making an icon with an sh script.

http://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

would it help if I said Chrome has a Kiosk mode?

http://think2loud.com/868-google-chrome-full-screen-kiosk-mode/

Comment: Thank you. Kiosk mode is working, but it still opens up tabbed. How can I remove the tabs and just show the url bar for example?